# Error with a main method

Tags: java, javac

So I was making a very basic program in java and this happened:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

Here is my "program"

```
public class GUI{
private JTextArea usernameInput;
private JTextArea licenceKeyOutput;
private JButton generateLicenceKeyButton;
private JPanel root;
private JPanel mainGUI;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    frame.setContentPane(new GUI().mainGUI);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public GUI() {
    generateLicenceKeyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(usernameInput.getText() == ""){
                System.err.println("[IntelliGen] Invalid username received, telling user");
                usernameInput.setText("Invalid Username");
                licenceKeyOutput.setText("Invalid Username");
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
}
```

NOTE: I made this program with IntelliJ Idea's GUI Creator.
It seems that the JDK is corrupted, but it works fine with other programs. Can you guys help me in any way?

Comment: How do you launch it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IntelliJ's launcher configuration `Main` class is set to `Main` which is invalid, in this case your `Main` class is `GUI`

```
Run > Edit Configuration > Main class:
```

Answer (score 0):

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main`

This means you are trying to run a class named main, but your class is named GUI